# conversion between OpenCV matrix and int matrix

Tags: c++, video, opencv, matrix, type-conversion

I am trying to read video frames with openCV, save data in cv::Mat form. then I want to use my another code which accepts "int type matrix" to this video frame. I know the "cvMat" and "int type matrix" are not compatible. Maybe I am not familiar with opencv, but can I do any kind of conversion between "cvMat" and "int mat", so that I can use my code for the captured video frames? 
I say "int mat", maybe it is not correct, but what I mean is this:

```
cv::Mat videoFrame;
int inputData[600][400];
```

I want to do something like:

```
inputData = videoFrame;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fast way is to share the memory: no copy needed. Though, if you modify one matrix, the other will be modified (obvious!)

```
int inputData[600][400];
cv::Mat videoFrame(600, 400, CV_32UC1, inputData);
```

Please note that any further OpenCV call on videoFrame that changes its type/size will allocate a new piece of memory where the result will be stored.

If you want to have separate data matrices, you may use memcpy -it's the fastest way to duplicate data:

```
memcpy((char*)inputData, (char*)videoFrame.data, 600*400*sizeof(int) );
```

The problem with this approach is that it's not safe at all. What if videoFrame is not of type int? (Most probably it is char). What if it's not continuously stored in memory (may happen)? ...

Comment: Dear Vasile, thank you so much for your answer. Your suggested method is quite good, but I am afraid of playing with memory allocation. Just as you mentioned, it might be not safe, and I've already experienced many memory problems so far (not for this case). So could there be another solution? I really don't hope my code might dead again because of memory problems. Thank you again.

Comment: The safe way is not to use inputData at all. Look at your algorithm, and see whether you can simply use videoFrame alone. Duplicating data is sometimes a sign of bad coding

Comment: When working with `cv::Mat`'s underlying data directly, be aware of any padding OpenCV may introduce, especially when passing it to other functions that expect contigous data. OpenCV may (and by-default will) introduce additional padding between rows to align them to 4 (or 8) byte boundaries. Although for a 32-bit integer (and/or such round row widths) there probably won't be any padding, it is something to keep in mind in general.

Comment: Be careful not to mix the width and the height! When specifying the dimensions of a 2D array or `cv::Mat`, its height comes before the width. So with @sammy's answer (and the original question), we're actually dealing with a 400x600 image here, not a 600x400 image.